# Middleware writes response when starting up the project

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, middleware

Using ASP.Net Core, C#

I  have a middleware where i check for particular cookie is present otherwise returning a 400 response. My problem is the middleware fires up starting the project itself and check the cookie is present or not and then shows the response text in the swagger index page, which i dont want.the middleware fies when swagger loads. I want this condition to be executed only for the requests.

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var pl = context.Request.Cookies["pl"];
            var sig = context.Request.Cookies["sig"];
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pl) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sig))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid Data");
                return;
            }
           // If success i process and do something
            
            // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
            await _next(context);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can prevent firing the middleware when swagger loads and fire only for api requests. But is this better approach or any other better are there.

```
app.UseWhen(context => `context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("/api"),HandleBranch);`
```